# Work outside the stage with AIR and Java

Tags: java, swing, actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to get mouse click coordinates and pixel color,where mouse click happened, outside the stage with AIR and/or Java?

or,if there is not standart way, does some one know some trick for that?

for example,trick in AIR, u can create fulscreen,transparent(to see where are u clicking) prog with 0.1 transparent mc with it, than get mouseX and mouseY where click has happened, than get fullScreenWidth and fullScreenHeight and than u will be able to calculate real coordinates..

Comment: Java? No. What is the specification/feature that has your app. needing that information?

Comment: i am going to use JavaRobot and want to know where to click, without coordiantes and color, i am blind, i will not be able to determine, when and where i have to click with robot,so, first i want to get coordinates and color with AIR(i am new in Java,so,as3 is more simple for me), than use that information in Java to determine click,when and where.. i don't see another way to accomplish this case

Comment: *"to know where to click"* ***Why*** to click? Try and explain it to me as the end of a sentence intended to appear as a feature on the shrink wrapped packaging "This software allows you to X?" What is X in that context?

Comment: i am creating program for personal purpose, i want it to do some desktop work for me, anyway,task is this, i want to click somewhere(AIR will give me coordinates,where), if that coordinate's pixel color,say, is blue,if it is red,wait until it becomes blue,than click it..than going step 2,AIR will give me another coordinates, and i will click there too,depends on pixel color and so on..

Comment: Well that's easy, and does not require 'detecting clicks' outside the application!

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: if it is easy, than tell me how to get coordinates first,than get appropriate color :) i managed to get coordinates,but i can not get color, JavaRobot can detect color on a specified coordinates,that is not what i need,first, i want to get that color with mannualy mouse click,outside the program...

Comment: there is no XY problem, so, in sum, i want to get coordinates and color outside that program, with Java or AIR, than i know how to use it with JavaRobot, just want mannualy mouse click info,outside the application.. how can i explain that more clear?

Comment: So, you already ***have*** the co-ordinates? Get a screenshot of the entire screen. Then query the returned `BufferedImage` to [`getRGB(x,y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-). Easy peasy.

Comment: u mean with AIR? yes,that will work, but how can i take a desktop screenshot? first, i may have to minimize AIR app, right? and if i minimize it, will it work? :)

Comment: 1) I've been meaning to point this out, but SO is not an SMS and not Twitter. Please spell all ***3*** letters of 'you'. 2) Tip: the `getRGB(x,y)` text above is a link. That should answer your first question above.

Comment: Instead of fullscreen transparent why dont you... **find** a command line screen grabber tool that you run as process via AIR code. Pass the required "grab" command (via **stdout**) and the result (image) comes back to your app where you do the rest (ie: checking specific colour of pixel). Look for a grabber tool that allows specifying a specific window or entire desktop itself as source of grab (this avoid minimize etc).

Comment: Thanks guys.. Andrew Thompson, you(i have spelled :)) are very loaded,relax man :)  i have solved my problem in a simpler way, i don't need screenshot at all, i will just get coordiantes from AIR, and Java Robot will tell me colors from a pointed coordinates, this is not convinient way but enough for now.. in future i will learn Java and will certainly find a way how to get mouse click coordinates outside the program,as i did in AIR, then i will combine getting coordinates and colors In Java and everything will be okay ;)